# Parents selector in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I need to get all elements whose n-th parent (i.e. elem.parent().parent()...parent()) has a specific class. Is that possible?

For example:

```
<div class="success">
  <div id="depth-1">
    <div id="depth-2">
      <div>Return me</div>
      <div>Return me</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

the command with parent depth of 3 and class "success" will return the `"Return me"` divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about n-deep, but this will get all divs whose great-grand-parent (n = 3) has the class `success`.

```
$('.success > * > * > div')
```

You could write a function to generate the selector. Something like:

```
function getNDeepSelector(n, className) {
    var selector = '.' + className, ii;
    for (ii = 0; ii < n; ii += 1) {
        selector += ' > *'
    }
    return selector;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, since I come from python, a nice solution would be 
$('.success' + " ".join(["> *"]*n). Is there something equivalent in jQuery?

Comment: It wouldn't be a jQuery specific function, as String is just a global JavaScript object. As far as I know, there isn't a construct like what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Child selector as follows:

```
var returnMe = $(".success > * > * > *");
```

Although in your particular example I would probably do:

```
var returnMe = $(".success div div div");
```